# iOS self.window - when is it created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, uiwindow

when you start your app using single view template, and you add the `NSLog(@"self.window = %@", self.window);` in your first line of the AppDelegate.m's `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, you can see that `self.window` exists in your app.

However, when you start your app using empty template, and tried to log the `self.window` to the console, the result returns `null`. Even if you add storyboard and a view controller, and set its view controller as the initial view controller, and attempt to log the `self.window`, the result is the same - its value is set to `null`.

And note that whichever way you take, you can find you declare `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;` in AppDelegate.h by default. So I wonder why in the first case, you can see that `self.window` is initialized and set the value but not in the latter case. Also, if `self.window` is already declared and initialized in the first case but NOT in the second case, how can I find the initialization code?

It looks like in both cases, the `@property` declaration is same - and in both cases, as I mentioned, I tried to log the value of `self.window` in the FIRST LINE of the `AppDelegate.m`'s `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

So anything that I'm missing? I don't know why those two cases act differently despite me not finding any differences in both code and storyboard.

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, when you create a project with a Storyboard or Nib then the project settings will tell the project that the storyboard/nib is the "Main Interface".

This triggers the application to load that interface on start up. This is why the `self.window` is created in these cases.

When you create an empty application there is no interface to set as the main interface.

You then need to create the window yourself like this...

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

     UIViewController *someController = [UIViewController... //create your initial controller

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Something like this anyway. It's been a while.

Alternatively, if you create an empty application and then add a nib file that you want to use as the initial nib then you can select it in the project settings.

In the Target in General. In the section "Deployment Info" select the "Main Interface" from the nibs in your project. This will then load that nib when the application starts.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! That's exactly what I'm asking... Then which way (writing code or setting on Target) would you recommend when starting the app using empty template?

Comment: If you're just using code and no nibs at all then you'll need to code it. If you're using a nib for your first view then set the Main Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode declares `UIWindow` as `IBOutlet` Object in `Appdelegate` and xcode itself hooks or connect it with the window of default ViewController.nib(Created by Xcode when you create non empty project).There is no need to initialise any object if you have declared it as Iboutlet and connected it with any UIController in nib.

Now in empty project if you want to create window declare it as outlet and connect it with window in exist in nib  and make your AppDelegate as Files OWner.