# What is the difference between UIviewcontroller and UIwindow?

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I am bit confused when I try to compare the difference between Uiviewcontroller and UI window?

Answer (score 2):

UIWindow is a subclass of UIView, it provides space for displaying content using a UIView, but it does not display anything on its own. Please read up [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow?language=objc) to get a full understanding. UIViewController is the object that controls a view, hence the name. This follows the basic iOS programming architecture MVC--Model View Controller: model holds data and behaviors, view displays information, and the controller is the connecting piece between the view and the model, more information on that topic [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html).

Comment: when is our first UI window object is created?

Comment: @subhashchandru, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380567/ios-self-window-when-is-it-created